# Different results using Python3 and Python2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

here's the code I'm testing:

```
def rule(n):
    rules_numbers = {128: 'xxx', 64: 'xx.', 32: 'x.x', 16: 'x..',
                     8: '.xx', 4: '.x.', 2: '..x', 1: '...'}
    rules = {'...': '.', '..x': '.', '.x.': '.', '.xx': '.', 'x..': '.', 'x.x': '.', 'xx.': '.', 'xxx': '.'}
    while n != 0:
        for r in rules_numbers:
            if n - r >= 0:
                rules[rules_numbers[r]] = 'x'
                n -= r
                break
    return rules


def cellular_automaton(string, pattern, n):
    if n == 0:
        return string
    rules = rule(pattern)
    ng = ""
    for j in range(len(string)):
        nxt = j + 1
        if j == len(string) - 1:
            nxt = 0
        ng += rules[string[j - 1] + string[j] + string[nxt]]
        j += 1
    return cellular_automaton(ng, pattern, n - 1)
```

Here are some sample inputs and the outputs that we should get if the code is correct:

```
print(cellular_automaton('.x.x.x.x.', 17, 2))
#>>> xxxxxxx..
print(cellular_automaton('.x.x.x.x.', 249, 3))
#>>> .x..x.x.x
print(cellular_automaton('...x....', 125, 1))
#>>> xx.xxxxx
print(cellular_automaton('...x....', 125, 2))
#>>> .xxx....
print(cellular_automaton('...x....', 125, 3))
#>>> .x.xxxxx
print(cellular_automaton('...x....', 125, 4))
#>>> xxxx...x
print(cellular_automaton('...x....', 125, 5))
#>>> ...xxx.x
print(cellular_automaton('...x....', 125, 6))
#>>> xx.x.xxx
print(cellular_automaton('...x....', 125, 7))
#>>> .xxxxx..
print(cellular_automaton('...x....', 125, 8))
#>>> .x...xxx
print(cellular_automaton('...x....', 125, 9))
#>>> xxxx.x.x
print(cellular_automaton('...x....', 125, 10))
#>>> ...xxxxx
```

Here is a video explaining the problem I tried to solve: https://youtu.be/M_pkidxeGMY

When I run this code using Python3 I get all the outputs right, when I do it using Python2 I get different results.
Can you pleae explain to me what part of the code makes the difference? Thanks!

resluts from Python2:

```
..xxxxxxx
.x.xxxxxx
xxx..xxx
..x.x...
xx....xx
.x.xxx..
x....x.x
x.xxx...
....x.xx
.xxx...x
...x.xx.
xxx...x.
```

Comment: how do those results differ from the output above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `rules()` function produces different results because it relies on the *dictionary iteration order*. Dictionaries do not have an ordering, and iteration over the keys is [implementation dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary). Python 3.6 switched implementations, and with that the iteration order changed too, for example.

For your first rule, number 17, I get the following results:

Python 2.7:

```
>>> sorted(rule(17).items())
[('...', 'x'), ('..x', 'x'), ('.x.', '.'), ('.xx', '.'), ('x..', '.'), ('x.x', '.'), ('xx.', '.'), ('xxx', '.')]
```

Python 3.6:

```
>>> sorted(rule(17).items())
[('...', 'x'), ('..x', '.'), ('.x.', '.'), ('.xx', '.'), ('x..', 'x'), ('x.x', '.'), ('xx.', '.'), ('xxx', '.')]
```

Note how `'..x'` is mapped to `'.'` in one, `'x'` in the other.

You'll have to alter your rules function to produce a fixed order. You could sort the keys, for example:

```
for r in sorted(rules_numbers):
```

Now all Python versions produce the same output:

```
>>> sorted(rule(17).items())
[('...', 'x'), ('..x', '.'), ('.x.', '.'), ('.xx', '.'), ('x..', '.'), ('x.x', '.'), ('xx.', '.'), ('xxx', '.')]
```